# How do I copy a file from a remote system to local?

Tags: scp, file-copy

I'm on a virtual machine trying to copy a file from SSH to local system. Using Debian. I don't see the "Connect to" option. When I try to do it trough terminal, I enter

```
scp [myusername@remote.system]:[path to the file obtained using "find"]
```

and it just gives me options for scp usage like -c etc
If I enter the above command and add Downloads, it says file name and 100%, size etc, but the Downloads folder is empty
What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: You missed out the destination.

Comment: It's not working, please help me

Comment: it says permissions denied and i even changed them to 777

Comment: Suggest giving the full command line you used and the error message too. Replace user@server.com with something clear that it has been changed. Without all the details we can only really guess as to what is wrong.

Comment: Post the actual command you ran (copy-paste). Copy-paste the full error message(s) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `cd`ing to the target directory and then doing the following:

1. `touch dummyfile` - check if you have the permissions to create locally.
2. Check you can SSH into the remote location and read the file you are trying to copy. Try `ssh -vvv` to debug connectivity and ssh key issues.
3. `scp user@remote .` - the dot here is the current directory, so scp should then copy the file locally.

Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scp remoteuser@server:.bash_history newfile
```

Only need to change two things:
 name of remoteuser & name of server

If it works you should end up with a file on the local PC called newfile.
There's a small chance that it doesn't work if you don't have .bash_history on the remote machine, but it's worth the gamble.